# Opportunity historical trending: I miss many fields

Tags: history-tracking, opportunity-history

Opportunity historical trending is enabled in our org, by default 5 specific fields are monitored. Salesforce allows to select 3 more fields, but offers only a choice from a few, 10 to be exact. We have dozens of fields, but only 10 are offered for selection for historical trending. I do not see any logic in the fields that are selectable. I am the admin of the org, I have permissions to see all fields.

In particular, I miss fields like Stage duration and Age. Anyone has an idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you can't select `Age` and `Stage Duration` is that they are in essence, formula fields and per the doc on [Historical Trending Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.reports_historical_limits.htm&type=5), formula fields aren't supported

The deeper reason is that Historical Trending records are written only on DML changes and `Age`, for example, changes value every day - but only by inspection (queryinq) the record. No DML occurs.

You could use normal [Reporting Snapshots](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.data_about_analytic_snap.htm&type=5) to capture (every day) the values of `Age` as Reporting Snapshots are summary/matrix reports of the underlying Opportunities. You then develop your own dashboards /reports based off the Reporting Snapshot records.